# reduce nuxt project loading time

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

So i have a nuxt app with vue2 and i'm using json-server for a local database and axios to fetch data.

When I run "npm run dev" the compilation (server and client) takes around 10 seconds but the application takes forever to render.I checked the network tab and I think it probably has something to do with the get request

```
GET /tests 200 32.933 ms - 604001
GET /tests 304 22.315 ms - -
GET /results 304 3.781 ms - -
```

Any idea how i can improve the performance on how i fetch the data from the server ?

here s how im using axios right now

```
data() {
    return {
      search: '', 
      tests :[]
}
async created() {
      try {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3004/tests`)
      
      
      this.tests=res.data;
      }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked your API? In a case of a timeout your function probably won't finish until the request times out, this can take a while. Enter `http://localhost:3004/tests` into your browser / use PostMan to debug your API.

Comment: the api is working fine and the page correctly renders everything.It's just taking way too long to load the app

Comment: So the data stored in the component is fine? Normally this should not be an issue. Try removing the `async` from your `created` hook and use `.then` to resolve the promise returned.

This sound like your API is just taking too long to return the response. Did your measure the time your API takes?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat nope, keep async/await and not not use `.then` as suggested above. At the end, it should not matter. Try to debug with Postman to double check that your API is fine, maybe try to load something else to try out that this is coming from this part (like JSONplaceholder). Otherwise, the issue is coming from somewhere else.